# Why is my Trigger not triggering (Unity, C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I work at the moment on my enemies but in the script they don't want to activate the trigger in the script :/

- I'm using the same script and trigger for every enemy (they only have different weapons)
- The transition doesn't have exit time
- Normally it should after Facetargetting me, starting to play animation because of trigger

This is the script:

```
public class Gegnerscript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float lookRadius = 10f;

    Transform target;
    NavMeshAgent agent;

    Animator animator;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        target = GegnerManager.instance.Player.transform;
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position);

        if (distance <= lookRadius)
        {
            agent.SetDestination(target.position);

            if (distance <= agent.stoppingDistance)
            {
                FaceTarget(); //is working
                // animator.SetTrigger("AngriffGegner");  // is not working/doesn't trigger
            }
        }       
    }

    void FaceTarget ()
    {
        Vector3 direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
        Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z));
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * 5f);
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.black;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, lookRadius);     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if agent.stoppingDistance > lookRadius, your trigger will not work.

Comment: How you mean? The Facetarget is working. So shouldnt the Trigger also work?

Comment: My answer is wrong. The problem may be in the blend tree.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you typed the name of the trigger exactly
because if there is any difference the trigger won't work

so check the trigger name in the unity editor and make sure it matches the name you typed in code (also check for capital and small letters they really matter)

Comment: I checked like 20 times, other ideas why it could not work?

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: you have discord?